# Refresh System Environment Variables for all processes without Logout/ Restart in C++

Tags: c++, environment-variables, registry, system-paths, windows-restart-manager

I am writing a program in c++ that adds a new directory to the path environment variable for the system. The directory is successfully added with the `RegSetValueEx()` function but the changes are not reflected for all processes.

I have tried `BroadcastSystemMessage()` and `SendMessageTimeout()` functions seperately as below

```
LPCTSTR keyPath = TEXT("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment");
        
BroadcastSystemMessage(0, 0, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)keyPath);
```

and

```
LPCTSTR keyPath = TEXT("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment");

SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)keyPath, SMTO_BLOCK, 100, NULL);
```

but they both dont work, however when i restart my system the changes are then reflected.

### **What i want**

I want the changes to be reflected for all process without logout and it is possible as few days ago i installed a software (Composer https://getcomposer.org) that added its environment path and refreshed the environment variables for all processes without requiring a system restart.

Here are some useful links i have already viewed

- [Set current user environment variable from c++ code visible to other process like cmds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025636/set-current-user-environment-variable-from-c-code-visible-to-other-process-lik)
- [Is there a command to refresh environment variables from the command prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w)

Comment: All those functions do is send a message to all applications notifying them that a setting has changed. If some applications choose to ignore that message there isn't much you can do. I find it unlikely that one application would be able to force an environment change on another application. That seems like a security flaw.

Comment: My bad, i was using the function incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what i was doing wrong, I was using

```
LPCTSTR keyPath = TEXT("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment");
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)keyPath, SMTO_BLOCK, 100, NULL);
```

when it should be

```
LPCTSTR keyPath = TEXT("Environment");
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)keyPath, SMTO_BLOCK, 100, NULL);
```

and this refreshed the environment variables for other processes without a restart.